# Typescript function that takes a base class and returns a subclass with generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to convert the following JS code to TypeScript, and ideally I'd like it to have proper typings:

```js
function makeSubclassA(BaseClass) {
  return class SubclassA extends BaseClass {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, I actually have a root base class `RootBaseClass`, and all `BaseClass`es are supposed to inherit from `RootBaseClass`.

Also, all base classes need to take two type parameter args `<R extends object, P extends object>` as well. So it's `RootBaseClass<R extends object, P extends object>`, `BaseClass` should also have the same args as well.

`makeSubclassA` is going to set both of those type arguments, so it doesn't need to take `R` and `P` args.

This is a full version, but without proper types:

```js
class RootBaseClass<R extends object, P extends object> {
  constructor() {}

  process(raw: R): P {
    throw new Error('Not implemented.')
  }

  // ... and some other functions that fetch from a URL
  // and pass raw data to `process()`, and save the
  // processed form in a database.
}

// Now, let's define two types to be used by SubclassA
interface RawA {
  F1: string;
  F2: string;
}

interface ProcessedA {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// This should return a class that extends `BaseClass<RawA, ProcessedA>`
function makeSubclassA(BaseClass) {
  return class SubclassA extends BaseClass {
    process(raw: RawA): ProcessedA {
      return {
        name: raw.F1,
        age: parseInt(raw.F2)
      };
    }
  };
}

// SubclassA is going to extend `SomeBaseClass` that extends `RootBaseClass`
class SomeBaseClass<R extends object, P extends object> extends RootBaseClass<R, P> {
  // override a few stuff from `RootBaseClass`
}

// I expect SubclassA to be a class that extends `BaseClass<RawA, ProcessedA>`
const SubclassA = makeSubclassA(SomeBaseClass);

const instance = new SubclassA();
```

I really appreciate a properly typed solution, or a concrete answer explaining why it is not possible in TypeScript. Let me know if more clarification is needed with the question.

Comment: Uh, could you provide something closer to a [mre] with what you've tried, including `RootBaseClass` and some demos of it being used?  I don't want to spend time working on it if I make incorrect guesses about use cases.

Comment: Oh ok sure I will add more details. :)

Comment: BTW, my guess is that you'll probably end up running into [ms/TS#16390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16390) and [ms/TS#37142](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37142) with a dash of [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), but the use case info will determine if and how one might work around those to meet your needs.

Comment: @jcalz I just added a more complete code, hope it helps. But I have the same feeling that it's not fully possible with TS as of now. I'm just not sure.

Comment: Your code doesn't use any of its generics or add any properties anywhere so it's hard to test; I made guesses and now I have [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjarYW) (with a single error that I needed to work around, see [ms/TS#52971](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52971)).  Without more of a [mre] from you I'm not sure whether that's what you're trying to do or not.

Comment: Thank you very much @jcalz, this is pretty much what I needed! The generics are going to be used by a function inside the classes. These classes are supposed to process some form of raw data into one of a few predefined "processed" forms. The code base is using mixins to handle data coming from various sources that have some similarities and some differences.

Comment: I just added the `process` function that uses the generic type args.

Comment: @jcalz no `process(r: R): P` takes an `R` and returns a `P`. The constructor doesn't take any args.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it doesn't return a `P`; it doesn't return *anything*.  Your example isn't a [mre] and I have to guess what's going on.  How does the root class turn an arbitrary `R` into an arbitrary `P` if the `process()` method doesn't do anything?  Again, I find myself guessing to make something that makes any sort of sense and I have [this version](https://tsplay.dev/weaoEw) now.  But if the constructor doesn't take any argument I'm completely confused. I might need to disengage unless I see a real [mre] here sometime (sorry if I'm being repetitive). Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz sorry for the confusion, and I really appreciate your help. I got what I needed from your example. `process` doesn't take an arbitrary `R`, and in the `RootBaseClass` this is defined as an abstract method that throws a `Not Implemented` error. I didn't include the definitions of the functions as I thought they're irrelevant. I wanted to focus on a way to pass correct type args in the `makeSubclassA` function. In any case, I added more details, but I'm not sure if it's enough...

Comment: Okay hopefully [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WGBjvm) works well enough for me to write it up as an answer.  Let me know if not.

Comment: Yes it definitely does! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you will get is probably

```
function makeSubclassA<T extends new () => RootBaseClass<RawA, ProcessedA>>(
    BaseClass: T) {
    return class SubclassA extends (
        BaseClass as typeof RootBaseClass<RawA, ProcessedA>
    ) {
        process(raw: RawA): ProcessedA {
            return {
                name: raw.F1,
                age: parseInt(raw.F2)
            };
        }
    } as new () => InstanceType<T>;
}
```

This doesn't actually require that `BaseClass` be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) class, which would be hard to express properly anyway without direct support for higher-kinded types as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  Instead, it just requires that `BaseClass` is a zero-arg constructor whose instances are assignable to `RootBaseClass<RawA, ProcessedA>`.  But that's all you wanted.

This produces more or less the result you want, except that TypeScript is unhappy with the [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) inside the implementation.  It is technically incorrect to assume that any concrete subclass that extends a *generic* base class will be compatible if sets or overrides anything from the base, since the generic base class might have a *more* specific version.  This is the TypeScript is meant to behave, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#52971](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52971).  I've worked around it with several [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

This works for the use cases mentioned in your question:

```
const SubclassA = makeSubclassA(SomeBaseClass);

const instance = new SubclassA();
console.log(instance.process({ F1: "a", F2: "123" }));
// {name: "a", age: 123}
console.log(instance.a.toFixed(2)); // "1.00"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6&ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=48&pc=46#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)